# Re-configure Raspberry Pi Boot Menu

Tags: boot

I got a new Raspberry Pi 3 model B and it came with NOOBS which allowed me to choose which items I want to install. I chose Raspbian and OSMC and ever since it offers a menu and then automatically boots Raspbian after 10 seconds.

What needs to be done to change the default timeout in seconds before an OS is booted?

Can I skip the boot screen altogether (perhaps with a hotkey to catch it)?

Can I add/remove items to the boot screen?

Answer (score 3):

1. Add `bootmenutimeout=5` to `/boot/cmdline.txt` to change the setting to 5 seconds. Notes for Noobs:

   - Use `sudo nano /boot/cmdline.txt` to edit the file.
   - Make sure you have a space before you add `bootmenutimeout=5` to the end of the line
   - Use Ctrl+X, Y, Enter to save and exit
2. The boot screen cannot be skipped automatically unless there is only on OS installed. You could set the timeout above to 1s. Haven't tried 0.
3. You can do a quick and dirty removal of an OS by removing it from the file `/media/pi/SETTINGS/installed_os.json`. Noob notes:

   - Use `sudo nano /media/pi/SETTINGS/installed_os.json` to edit the NOOBS menu
   - Find the section between the `{}` brackets referring to your OS
   - Note the partition numbers (e.g. /dev/mmcblk0p6 and /dev/mmcblk0p7)
   - Remove that section as well as the comma on the line before your `{`. So remove your section and ensure you have `}` and not `},` before your removed section
   - Ctrl+X, Y, Enter to save
   - You can now reboot or run `sudo cfdisk /dev/mmcblk0` to delete the partition numbers noted above
   - Reboot and the OS should be gone, here's where you might wish you had backed up your installed_os.json file first!
   - To actually regain the lost space is very tricky and not attempted here!
4. You can add an OS by rebooting and holding Shift untill you reach the NOOBS recovery menu. Select a new OS and install it.

Answer (score 1):

See [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/33037/how-to-add-delay-at-boot).
Basically, there's a file at `/boot/config.txt` where you can set boot delays in seconds (`boot_delay=`) or miliseconds (`boot_delay_ms=`)

Comment: This won't do it. According to the docs[1] the `boot_delay` is just a delay giving hardware a chance to start. It has nothing to do with the timeout of the boot menu. I think `boot_delay` applies to the pi before it even gets to the boot menu.

[1]https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt.md

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you check out the NOOBS advanced documentation which is stored with the github sources.

https://github.com/raspberrypi/noobs#how-to-bypass-the-recovery-splashscreen-and-boot-directly-into-a-fixed-partition

Gordon

Answer (score 0):

Try [this documentation](http://www.berryterminal.com/doku.php/berryboot) for BerryBoot. There's two text files `cmdline.txt` and `config.txt` that have options in them, including `bootmenutimeout=<seconds>`. Change that option to `nobootmenutimeout`.

According to [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/6972/location-of-berryboots-config-txt), these 2 text files should be located in the root of your main partition.

Comment: Sorry, I've since discovered it's definitely NOOBS and updated the question,.